# window.name as an alternative to cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I require to store unique data for each tab/window of the same session hence I cannot use cookies. Also these days chrome appears to retain session cookies across restarts of browser. So I am using window.name as the way to store the required data.

My use of window.name is with in a script that can be embedded by others. So I would like to know which other libraries use window.name (I believe its used for cross domain data transport)?

Comment: Have you tried `location.hash` to store tab specific data?

Comment: But I need the data across page navigations. Also if the webpage is already using a hash?

Comment: You can hook into the `onclick` of your links to perpetuate it; if there's already a hash, you have to come up with something smarter :)

Answer (score -1):

`window.name` isn't preserved across different domains in modern browsers, hence it was abandoned for cross domain data transport.

Comment: Is there any other way window.name is used by other libraries? I don't want to break another library when my script is included.

Comment: It might be used for cross domain transport if a website targets old browsers and uses an old library. Also, if a form targets a window with a specific name and you change the name unexpectedly. i.e., `<form target=bird><input type=submit></form><iframe name=bird src="">`